# migrated rails3 app to heroku, now paperclip+s3 not uploading files - nothing in heroku logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

Hi I just migrated to heroku cedar stack. app is Rails 3, ive been using paperclip on s3 just fine previously. my gemfile has:

gem 'paperclip', '2.3.11'
gem 'aws-s3', '0.6.2'

my model file has:

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
has_attached_file :avatar, 
                :styles => { :thumb  => "150x200#" }, 
                :default_style => :thumb, 
                :default_url => "missingAvatar.png",
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS
```

Ive created a new file to store S3_CREDENTIALS,:

```
# initializers/s3.rb
if Rails.env == "production"
  # set credentials from ENV hash
S3_CREDENTIALS = { :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'], :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET'], :bucket => "app_content"}
else
  # get credentials from YML file
S3_CREDENTIALS = Rails.root.join("config/s3.yml")
end
```

... with s3.yml containing my keys for local dev, and the keys set in heroku config:
    S3_KEY              => AK...
    S3_SECRET           => FFE...

as mentioned, everything works just fine on local. i can even see the existing avatars from before. just, when i try to upload anything new, i get no errors in heroku logs, but the picture never uploads.

ive went thru many stackoverflow issues, but none matching this. can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your model

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
has_attached_file :avatar, 
                :styles => { :thumb  => "150x200#" }, 
                :default_style => :thumb, 
                :default_url => "missingAvatar.png",
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS,
                :url  => "/assets/avatar/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/avatar/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

The missing path / default path might be causing an issue.

Comment: Thanks, ive tried messing around with the :url and :path variables a lot thinking it might be something like that, or perhaps a heroku folder permissions thing... but no difference :(

Comment: have you verified your s3 credentials and bucket?

Comment: yes im using the same exact info in my other (non-Heroku) environment.

Answer (score 0):

turns out i needed to upgrade my paperclip gem to '2.4.5'
i did this in my Gemfile, then bundle update, and it worked!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but unfortunately your fix didn't help.  :(

Comment: im on heroku cedar stack - rails 3.0. are you rolling 3.1? it may require another updte

Comment: Yeah, I'm rolling 3.1.  I found my issue, when converting to Cedar, you have to update your config file to allow for static images to be displayed.  That's why I was getting "missing" file.  It just so happened that my static image file was the default "missing" file for paperclip.  Paperclip was a complete red herring, it just looked like the same issue I encountered when first setting up paperclip.